# About query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm recently doing a project with neo4j and got a question about the query in neo4j.

can someone tell me the difference between the following queries

```
Match (u:User {username:"admin"}) return u
```

and

```
Match (u:User) where u.username = "admin" return u
```

they seem return the same result on my sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `PROFILE` both queries you will see that they are literally the same; it is just two syntactically different ways of achieving exactly the same result.

```
PROFILE
MATCH (u:User {username:"admin"}) 
RETURN u
```

And ...

```
PROFILE
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE u.username = "admin" 
RETURN u
```